# Get scrip error(recaptcha) if login Dropbox failed first time

Tags: dropbox, recaptcha

I am using Webbrowse control in WPF to load Dropbox login page. Recently I got a problem that if user login with wrong password first time, then next time with the right password, it will bring a script error on "Allow page". This only happened if the user types the wrong password before. The error message show "https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1523860362251/recaptcha_en.js".

I google as far as I can, I have already target the webbrowser to IE 11, but the same issue still in there, I test with IE browser without any problem. Could you give me some advice how to fix this one?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference:  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Get-scrip-error-recaptcha-if-login-Dropbox-failed-first-time/m-p/273987#M16303 ]